# Haskell IO, getting two input in the same line and doing validation

Tags: validation, parsing, haskell, types, io

```
module TicTacToe (tictactoe) where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State

import Data.Char
import Data.List

import Text.Printf

tictactoe :: IO ()
tictactoe = do
  let grid = [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
  let count = 0
  output_grid grid count
  
  
output_grid :: String -> Int -> IO()
output_grid grid count = do
  putStr ".---.---.---.\n"
  printf "| %c | %c | %c |\n" (grid !! 0) (grid !! 1) (grid !! 2)
  putStr ".---.---.---.\n"
  printf "| %c | %c | %c |\n" (grid !! 3) (grid !! 4) (grid !! 5)
  putStr ".---.---.---.\n"
  printf "| %c | %c | %c |\n" (grid !! 6) (grid !! 7) (grid !! 8)
  putStr ".---.---.---.\n" -- output grid
  if count `mod` 2 == 0 
    then putStr "O MOVE\n"
    else putStr "X MOVE\n" -- tell player which to move
  if count `mod` 2 == 0
    then player_input grid 'O' count
    else player_input grid 'X' count


player_input :: String -> Char -> Int -> IO()
player_input grid sym count = do
  inp <- getLine
  let x = (read (takeWhile (/= ' ') inp) :: Int)
  let y = (read (drop 1 (dropWhile (/= ' ') inp)) :: Int)
  if (x < 1) || (x > 3) || (y < 1) || (y > 3)
    then putStr "INVALID POSITION \n"
    else return ()
  if (x < 1) || (x > 3) || (y < 1) || (y > 3)
    then player_input grid sym count
    else return ()
  let target = (x - 1) * 3 + (y - 1)
  if (grid !! target /= ' ')
    then putStr "INVALID POSITION \n"
    else return ()
  if (grid !! target /= ' ')
    then player_input grid sym count
    else return ()
  let new_grid = (take target grid) ++ [sym] ++ (drop (target + 1) grid)
  if (check_win new_grid sym)
    then output_terminate new_grid sym
    else if count == 8
      then output_terminate new_grid 'D'
      else output_grid new_grid (count + 1)


  
check_win :: String -> Char -> Bool
check_win grid sym = do
  if (grid !! 0 == sym) && (grid !! 1 == sym) && (grid !! 2 == sym)
    then True
    else if (grid !! 3 == sym) && (grid !! 4 == sym) && (grid !! 5 == sym)
      then True
      else if (grid !! 6 == sym) && (grid !! 7 == sym) && (grid !! 8 == sym)
      then True
        else if (grid !! 0 == sym) && (grid !! 3 == sym) && (grid !! 6 == sym)
          then True
          else if (grid !! 1 == sym) && (grid !! 4 == sym) && (grid !! 7 == sym)
            then True
            else if (grid !! 2 == sym) && (grid !! 5 == sym) && (grid !! 8 == sym)
              then True
              else if (grid !! 0 == sym) && (grid !! 4 == sym) && (grid !! 8 == sym)
                then True
                else if (grid !! 2 == sym) && (grid !! 4 == sym) && (grid !! 6 == sym)
                  then True
                  else False


output_terminate :: String -> Char -> IO()
output_terminate grid winner = do
  putStr ".---.---.---.\n"
  printf "| %c | %c | %c |\n" (grid !! 0) (grid !! 1) (grid !! 2)
  putStr ".---.---.---.\n"
  printf "| %c | %c | %c |\n" (grid !! 3) (grid !! 4) (grid !! 5)
  putStr ".---.---.---.\n"
  printf "| %c | %c | %c |\n" (grid !! 6) (grid !! 7) (grid !! 8)
  putStr ".---.---.---.\n"
  if winner == 'D'
    then putStr "DRAW \n"
    else printf "%c WINS \n" winner
```

I am a beginner in Haskell and I am working on a small TicTacToe game. This is the function that I used to get the player to input the coordinate of the symbol, like **2 2** (this will means that the symbol placing at the centre), they want to put into. And I want to add some validation feature on it. By now, it can only handle out of range inputs like **12 2**, and avoiding overwriting the occupied grids. But I want to do more. For example, **2** (only 1 input), **1 2 xy** (xy not supposed to be here), and **abcde** (random input not making sense). I want to make the program also able to handle these invalid input.

Comment: Can you include your other functions (`output_terminate`, `output_grid`, `main`, and `check_win`) so we can run the program? It would greatly help with testing.

Comment: 1. `return` means something different from most other languages, it doesn't exit early. 2. Parse, don't validate. https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/

Comment: I have updated the code with the other functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general suggestion, it's usually cleaner if we separate validation from user interaction. We could use a custom type for the validation result.

```
data Validation
  = CorrectMove Int Int      -- correct input
  | OutOfBounds              -- off the board
  | NonEmpty                 -- can not play on the same cell twice
  | ParseError               -- input is not two integers
```

Using the above, we can define a custom function for validation. (Below, I exploit `Text.Read.readMaybe` for simplicity, but `reads` from `Prelude` can also be used with minor changes.)

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

validate 
   :: String         -- ^ the user input
   -> String         -- ^ the grid (should be its own type)
   -> Validation
validate input grid = case words input of
   [xStr, yStr] -> -- two words, let's parse them
      case (readMaybe xStr, readMaybe yStr) of
         (Just x, Just y)
            | x < 1 || x > 3 || y < 1 || y > 3 -> OutOfBounds
            | cell grid x y /= ' '             -> NotEmpty
            | otherwise                        -> CorrectMove x y
         _ -> ParseError -- two words, but not two integers
   _ -> ParseError  -- not two words
```

The above exploits a custom grid-accessing function which we define below:

```
-- coordinates must be in-bounds
cell :: String -> Int -> Int -> Char
cell grid x y = grid !! ((x - 1) * 3 + y - 1)
```

After that, we can exploit our validation when we perform user interaction:

```
player_input :: String -> Char -> Int -> IO()
player_input grid sym count = do
  inp <- getLine
  case validate inp grid of
     ParseError  -> putStrLn "Invalid input!"
     NonEmpty    -> putStrLn "Cell not empty!"
     OutOfBounds -> putStrLn "Invalid coordinates!"
     CorrectMove x y -> do
        putStrLn $ "ValidMove in cell " ++ show (x,y)
        -- here we can use x and y, knowing they are valid
        -- and update the game state
```